# Drop Down List VLOOKUP Returns Multiple Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a VLOOKUP that returns multiple names when it matches with a color while using a drop down list.

I created this down list.

[image: The Drop Down List]

and associated VLOOKUP to reference the drop down list, but I know that it can only return one value at a time. Is there a way to go about returning multiple values?

[image: VLOOKUP]

So Basically if I'd like when I select a color from the drop down list to return this.

[image: something like this]

As you can see from my VLOOKUP, I'm referencing this table array on another sheet.

[image: This Table Array]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I provided enough information, if not please let me know and I'll provide as needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this `=IFERROR(INDEX('Customer Health Data'!$A$3:$A$36, SMALL(IF($A$1='Customer Health Data'!$C$3:$C$37, ROW('Customer Health Data'!$C$3:$C$37)-ROW('Customer Health Data'!$C$3)+1), ROW(1:1))),"" )`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and copy it to below cells.

If Cell `A1`= Yellow then the list of data with Yellow appears

[image: Search Sheet]

Sample data sheet for Customer Health Data

[image: Customer Health Data Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

`Vlookup` won't be able to do it, without a lot of tweaking.  Instead, you can use an `Index` formula, with `Small`.

This is a simple example, so adjust the ranges as necessary:

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$11=$D$1,ROW(B$1:B$11)-ROW(B$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1)))`

Where: `A1:A11` has what you want to return (in your case, the hospital names).  `B1:B11` has the Colors you want to search with.  **Note the cell anchoring**

Enter as an array formula (with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) and drag down.  You'll get `#NUM` errors once it exhausts your matches, so just wrap `IfError([formula],"")` around it to hide that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using a INDEX. I'm not too familiar with Excel so I don't have a lot of experience with various formulas.

I adjusted your formula to match my needs, however, I'm not getting the return of the multiple hospital names.


=INDEX(Customer Health Data!$A$3:$A$759,SMALL(IF(Customer Health Data!$C$3:$C$759=L4,ROW(Customer Health Data!$B$3:Customer Health Data!$C$759)-ROW(Customer Health Data!$C$3)+1),ROWS(Customer Health Data!$C$3:C3)))

Comment: @M.Mill - (Sorry for my delay in getting back to you) - What's the formula resolving to? If an error, what error does it show? If it's finding something, but not the right one, let me know.  (You're using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, yes?)